# In group interview, do candidates who are asked more questions than others have higher chance to be admitted?

Tags: interviewing

In a group interview, the interviewees come from different backgrounds. However, some of them are asked more questions than the others. While the interviewer has to cut down the time to interview everyone, the time length the interviewer spends for such candidates is noticeably longer than the other.

What could be interpreted for this situation? Should I be worried about my chances if I'm not getting asked as many questions?

Comment: When you say asked longer, what do you mean? Asked more questions? Talked to for longer? Asked to stay longer? Asked how long their fingers are?

Comment: Doesn't matter, group interviews are a stupid idea, run away without hesitation.

Comment: @Draken their work or life background

Comment: @MaskedMan can you explain why?

Comment: They're stupid yes, but I got the best job I ever had after group interview. I also got the worst. I wouldn't suggest running, but don't read anything into them.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep why is that stupid at the first place?

Comment: We have no way to know this. This is going to depend greatly on the interviewer and the candidates for that specific job.

Comment: This is a good list of why they're bad. I don't agree that you should avoid them, but be aware of basically what they are. http://www.chicagonow.com/get-employed/2012/06/5-reasons-not-to-do-a-group-interview/

Comment: Christopher's link has some pretty good reasons, one more point not explicitly covered there is group interviews require you to constantly put down other candidates (or at least, that is how they end up). I don't want to spend my interview time figuring out how good or bad *other* candidates are.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/why-is-the-question-about-group-interview-is-company-specific).

Answer (score 3):

Not always. In some cases, the opposite is true, especially in high pressure workplaces.

For example:

1. You have a candidate who has a solid CV, has answered a simple
   question absolutely fine, seems like a good hire.
2. You also have a less-solid on paper candidate who isn't opening up
   on the shorter questions. A deeper, more probing question allows a
   more focused assessment of that person. It has no effect on the
   performance (or standing) of the first candidate.

If, following this greater opportunity, candidate 2 does not perform, candidate 1 is a lock. If they do well, then it comes down to other factors.